# re-execute single job in jekins from parallel build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops

Is there any way to re-run only single job in parallel job config in Jenkins?

for example:  in given picture there is a Testing stage and in testing stage there is 3 parallel jobs 1,2 and 3. if job 1 will get failed , can we re-run only job 1 again , instead of executing Testing stage again?  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ4k9.png)

Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
agent {
    label "agent1"
}
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        parallel {
            stage('Test1') {
                steps { sh 'echo Test 1 passed' }
            }
            stage('Test2') {
                steps {
                    sh 'echo Test2 is passed'
                }
            } stage('Test3') {
                steps {
                    sh 'echo Test 3 passed'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If job 1 is a standalone Jenkins job you can just go to that job and rerun it. If you want to rerun a single stage checkout this documentation https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/running-pipelines/.

Comment: If you see in image i attached, there are 3 jobs running  parallelly under stage testing. when i am restating job 1.. its restarting all the three jobs again but i need to run only one job from the stage.

Comment: It might be helpful if you post your Jenkinsfile or a generic version of your Jenkinsfile so that we can take a look at it. Saying that those are 3 different jobs is confusing. If they are their own jobs being triggered from this build then you can just go directly to the job and rerun it. If those are actually tasks running in parallel in the stage, thats a different question. But ultimately we need to see your Jenkinsfile. The answer will be different depending on if you are using Declarative vs a scripted approach.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env groovy
pipeline {
    agent {
        label "agent1"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            parallel {
                stage('Test1') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'echo Test 1 passed'
                    }  }
                stage('Test2') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'echo Test2 is passed'
                    } }
                stage('Test3') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'echo Test 3 passed'
                    }} }} }}

Comment: in Test stage , if Test1 is failed, i want to re-run only failed job not Full Test stage again.

Comment: I tested this out a few different ways and it seems that Jenkins doesn't support restarting a stage inside of a parallel stage like you want to do. You can only restart the top level "Test" stage. It's possible they will add this feature in the future, you could open a defect with the Jenkins project to add it. You could explore this https://docs.huihoo.com/jenkins/enterprise/14/user-guide-docs/workflow-sect-checkpoint.html, which might let you add checkpoints to each stage and restart from that checkpoint but I don't want to install this plugin to check.